# where to place my error statement within my case statement

Tags: c, for-loop, switch-statement

I am writing a case statement in C. It adds a new player on the roster. I'm unsure of where to add my error statement. If the select jersey is not within the saved array I need to output that to the user with a printf such as "Player not in roster".

When I place it before my for loop it recognizes that the element isn't in the array but does not output the error statement. If I place the error inside, it loops for however many players are there and says "Player not in roster":

```
//case r allows for a player to be replaced
case 'r':
    printf("Enter a jersey number:\n");
    int replace;
    scanf("%d", &replace);
    for (int i = 0; i < numPlayers; ++i) {
        //if the user input matches a jersey in the array the user will input a new jersey number and rating
        if (replace == jerseyNumber[i]) {
            printf("Enter a new jersey number:\n");
            scanf("%d", &jerseyNumber[i]);
            printf("Enter a rating for the player:\n");
            scanf("%d", &playerRating[i]);
        }
        //else the error statement will tell the user that the player is not in the array
        else {
            printf("Player not in roster\n");
        }
    }
```

Comment: This would probably be best from a high-level point-of-view with a map instead of an array?

Comment: @Neil: C does not provide maps as a built-in or library feature.

Comment: Edit the question to show a [mre]. In particular, you need to explain what the “saved array” is and what it means for “the select jersey” to be not within the “saved array.” You should also show your code that attempts to determine whether or not the select jersey is within the saved array.

Comment: The implementation of the map is left as an exercise. :] Suggest a simple one first: `struct player { struct player *next; unsigned jersey, rating; } players[100], *hash[512]; size_t no_players; static struct player *lookup(const unsigned jersey) { struct player *entry = hash + jersey % (sizeof hash / sizeof *hash); while(entry && jersey != entry->jersey) entry = entry->next; return entry; };` . . .

Comment: If your player numbers are bounded, (I've never seen a three digit number?), you could actually fit a map of all digits of problem size into a perfect hash `struct jersey { int active; unsigned rating; } jerseys[100];`.

Answer (score 1):

IMO, the most straight-forward approach here is using a flag with your `for` loop.  A hash table has been recommended in the comments, I think that, or any other "better" data structure, is overkill, since you'd have to implement it yourself (if using C++, sure, use `std::map`).  While certainly more efficient, even a team with a large roster like football will only have 50-60 players on it.  Unless you need extreme speed, a `for` loop will suffice.  Dealing with thousands of different records would change my mind.

```
#include <stdbool.h>

...

case 'r':
    bool playerFound = false;
    printf("Enter a jersey number:\n");
    int replace;
    // you should check the return value of all your scanf calls, but
    // omitting that here for clarity
    scanf("%d", &replace);  // as mentioned in the comments, this should be replace
    for (int i = 0; i < numPlayers; ++i) {
        if (replace == jerseyNumber[i]) {
            printf("Enter a new jersey number:\n");
            scanf("%d", &jerseyNumber[i]);
            printf("Enter a rating for the player:\n");
            scanf("%d", &playerRating[i]);
            playerFound = true;
            break; // jersey numbers are unique for each player,
                   // so this is the one and only match, we're done searching
        }
    }
    // check if the player was found here after the loop
    if (playerFound == false)
    {
      // print your error message here
      puts("Player not in roster.");
    }
    break;
```